# Staging files on google dataflow worker

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Is there anything in the Dataflow SDK that would allow me to stage resource files on a worker?   I have specific static file resources that I need to make available on the file system for a custom DoFn that is performing NLP.  My goal would is to get a zip file resource from the classloader and unzip it on the worker file system only once as the worker is being initialized rather than trying to do this in the custom DoFn.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify `--filesToStage` to specify files that should be staged. There are several issues to be aware of:

1. By default, the Dataflow SDK sets `--filesToStage` to all of the files in your classpath, which ensures that the code needed to run your pipeline is available to the worker. If you override this option you'll need to make sure that it includes your code.
2. The files on the worker (which will be in the classpath) will have a MD5 hash appended to them. So if you specified `--filesToStage=foo.zip`, the file name would be `foo-<someHash>.zip`. You would need to iterate over all the files in the classpath to find the appropriate one.

See the documentation on `--filesToStage` in https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/executing-your-pipeline 
for some more info.

Comment: My question was more related to a "hook"  or API where I could pull a file from the "staged resources" one time on the worker node before it's starts performing the work.  I am able to stage the file that I need, but I can't find where I could retrieve and expand the resource locally before any work is performed on a node.   I've done this in the "startBundle" method in a DonFn, but I don't think thats the best way to do this given these are common to any worker.   This are static files that need to be on the local file system because of the NLP libraries that are being used.

Comment: I have a similar usecase. I have multiple model files to be used for prediction. The files are close to 1 GB. I dont want to load the files when execution because it will increase execution time. Should I load those files into staging location?