# Why is DataflowRunner putting some kind of hash value into the staged jars filename?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

When DataflowRunner starts it uploads jars files to the staging location. Why does it generate what seems to be hash values at the end of the jar name? And how is this hash generated? Is it to support jar files with changing contents as in SNAPSHOTS?

e.g. `beam-sdks-java-harness-2.18.0.jar` becomes `beam-sdks-java-harness-2.18.0-zSYSExFXVnBkN_8dj0glwg.jar`

I would much rather prefer to leave the name as is, because then I could use `gsutil -m cp ...` to speed-up uploading. Alternatively, a multi-upload functionality could be added to the existing mechanism.

Also, where can I submit issues or feature requests for DataflowRunner? Currently, it does not expand file globs e.g. `target/libs/*`, so I do it myself with a shell script, but I would like to see this as a core feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to find information on [Github](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/util/GcsStager.java):

> Stages files to {@link DataflowPipelineOptions#getStagingLocation()},
>   suffixed with their md5 hash to avoid collisions.

The files will have a MD5 hash appended to them. So the file name would be `file-<someHash>.zip`. The MD5 message-digest algorithm is a widely used hash function producing a 128-bit hash value.

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30516965/staging-files-on-google-dataflow-worker) Stackoverflow thread.
You can create issue or feature request for Dataflow [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list).

I hope it helps.